# jQuery attach event handler in each loop

Tags: jquery, event-handling, javascript-objects, each, jquery-events

I have an options object like this:

```
//buttons = html-button elements with id's
buttonTypes: {
"open" : ['#button1', '#button2'], 
"close" : ['#button3', '#button4'] 
}
```

Now I want to assign click handlers to the elements in each `buttonTypes.key`.
The buttons which are related to "open" shall call a function with the same name
and those related to "close" shall call a function called close
so I wrote this loop:

```
for(a in buttonTypes) {
    $(buttonTypes[a]).each(function(i,button){ 
        $(button).click(function(e) {
            that[a]();
        });
    });
}
```

The problem:

When I click on the buttons, the only function called is `close()` - so it seems it is always the last one. What do I do wrong?

Comment: I (as I asked this question 8 yrs ago) do not agree that the answer was already given in the linked post and this one was a duplicate at the time. This question was not about scope and the code was jQuery not vanilla JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `that[a]();` isn't evaluated until you click the button; and by that point, it's `close`.

What you should do instead is create a local copy of `a`;

```
for (a in buttonTypes) {
    $(buttonTypes[a]).each(function(i,button){
        var type = a;

        $(button).click(function(e) {
            that[type]();
        });
    });
}
```

Also don't forget to `var` a (`for (var a in buttonTypes)`).

Comment: yay, was it :-) you're right, thanks!